# Convert a List to multidimensional Map

Tags: java, java-8

I'd like to transform (with **Java8**) a list of (JSON) data to a hierarchical structure.

Could you please tell me what is the best way to deal with this?

How can I convert an **arraylist** to a **multidimensional map**?

The problem is something like converting this:

```
{
"server": "Manufacturer Co.",
"vehicles": [
    {
        "year": 2018,
        "model": "Ford Explorer (1)",
        "category": "4WD"
    },
    {
        "year": 2018,
        "model": "Ford Explorer (2)",
        "category": "4WD"
    },
    {
        "year": 2017,
        "model": "Ford Mustang (3)",
        "category": "2WD"
    }
    {
        "year": 2017,
        "model": "Ford Mustang 4WD (4)",
        "category": "4WD"
    }
}
```

into that

```
vehicles
-- year 2018
----- category: 4WD
---------- Ford Explorer (1)
---------- Ford Explorer (2)
-- year 2017
----- category: 2WD
---------- Ford Mustang (3)
----- category: 4WD
---------- Ford Mustang (4)
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you want to convert an ArrayList object to a Map then you need to show us the definition and content of that list, not some json structure. Add the code for your list and what you have tried in converting it to a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use multiple `groupingBy` and then use `mapping` to collect model property to list.

I'v supposed you have a model something like this:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private int year;
    private String model;
    private String category;

    //other 
}


Map<Integer,Map<String,List<String>>> result =  vehicles.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Vehicle::getYear,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Vehicle::getCategory, 
                            Collectors.mapping(Vehicle::getModel, Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: Wow! You save my week! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches. First one would be to create a `Map` with key `Year` of `Map`s with key `Category` of `Model`s. Iterate through all vehicles, create an entry for a year if it doesn't exist, add a category if it doesn't exist and add a model if it doesn't exist.

A bit more elegant approach would be to use an in-memory database. Create a table `vehicles` with columns `year`, `category` and `model` and then query it with:

```
select year, category, model
from   vehicle
order by year, category;
```